# Probability of a subset of Erlang distributed random variables being greater than the rest of the set

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, combinations

Consider $M$ independent, but not identically Erlang distributed random variables (RVs) $X_i \sim Erlang(k_i, \lambda_i)$, $i = 1,2,...,M$, with $k_i$ and $\lambda_i$ being the shape and the rate parameters as defined on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution). I am trying to find the probability of all of the first N RVs ($X_1,...,X_N$) being greater than all of the remaining $M-N$ RVs ($X_{N+1},...,X_M$). The order of $X_1,...,X_N$ does not matter. The probability density functions (pdf) and the cumulative distribution functions (cdf) are denoted as $f_{X_i}$ and $F_{X_i}$, respectively. By introducing a new random variable $Y = min\{X_1,...,X_N\}$ (first order statistic), the probability can be stated as
$$Pr(X_1,...,X_N \ greater \ than \ the \ rest)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_Y(x) P(X_1,...,X_N \ greater \ than \ the \ rest | Y=x) dx$$

where

$$f_Y(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}f_{X_i}(x) \prod_{j=1,j \neq i}^{N}(1-F_{X_j}(x))$$
and
$$P(X_1,...,X_N  \ greater \ than \ the \ rest| Y=x) = \prod_{l=N+1}^{M}F_{X_l}(x)$$
as $X_{N+1},...,X_M$ must be smaller than $Y$.
When replacing the general pdfs and cdfs with the ones of the Erlang distribution, the equation becomes
$$Pr(X_1,...,X_N \ greater \ than \ the \ rest)= \int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{\lambda_i^{k_i} x^{k_i -1} e^{-\lambda_i x}}{(k_i -1)!} \prod_{j=1,j \neq i}^{N}(1-P(k_j,\lambda_j x)) \prod_{l=N+1}^{M} P(k_l,\lambda_l x) dx$$

with $P$ being the [lower regularized Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Regularized_Gamma_functions_and_Poisson_random_variables). As $k_i$ is an integer for every $i$ as defined in the Erlang distribution, the lower regularized gamma function can be rewritten according to [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html).

$$Pr(X_1,...,X_N \ greater \ than \ the \ rest)= \int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{\lambda_i^{k_i} x^{k_i -1} e^{-\lambda_i x}}{(k_i - 1)!} \prod_{j=1,j \neq i}^{N}(e^{-\lambda_j x} \sum_{m=0}^{k_j-1}\frac{(\lambda_j x)^{m}}{m!}) \prod_{l=N+1}^{M} (1-e^{-\lambda_l x}\sum_{n=0}^{k_l-1}\frac{(\lambda_l x)^{n}}{n!}) dx$$

I am stuck at this point wondering whether there is a way to simplify the expression that is integrated such that I do not have to expand the whole expression and then integrate each individual term.